# Edittext to ratingbar in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my first question here so I would ask you not to be tough on me if I violate some rules, etc.

I am developing an Android project with a ratingbar. I try to get a number from edittext and pass its value to the ratingbar. I get a nullpointerexception and can't get past this, any help will be appreciated.

Here is the portion of relevant code:

```
    public void bindView(View movieView, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        final Movie movie = new Movie(cursor);

        Holder holder = (Holder)movieView.getTag();
        holder.setMovie(movie);

        TextView movieTitleText = (TextView)movieView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitleText); 
        TextView movieDescriptionText = (TextView)movieView.findViewById(R.id.movieDescriptionText); 
        RatingBar rb = (RatingBar)movieView.findViewById(R.id.movieRatingBar);
        rb.setNumStars(5);
        rb.setMax(5);
        rb.setRating(2.4F);

        rb.setEnabled(false);
        rb.setFocusable(false);

        float numRate = 0;
        numRate = Float.parseFloat(movie.getRating().toString());
        rb.setRating(numRate);

        movieTitleText.setText(movie.getTitle());
        movieDescriptionText.setText(movie.getDescription());


        movieView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Short click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent editIntent = new Intent(MoviesActivity.this, EditMovieActivity.class);
            editIntent.putExtra("isNew",false);
            editIntent.putExtra("title", movie.getTitle());
            editIntent.putExtra("description", movie.getDescription());
            editIntent.putExtra("year", movie.getYear());
            editIntent.putExtra("rating", movie.getRating());
            editIntent.putExtra("rottenId", movie.getRottenId());
            editIntent.putExtra("smallImage", movie.getSmallImage());
            editIntent.putExtra("largeImage", movie.getLargeImage());
            startActivityForResult(editIntent,EDIT_MOVIE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        movieView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder editBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoviesActivity.this);

            editBuilder.setTitle("Edit or Clear Movie").setMessage("Please choose either to clear or to edit the movie");

            editBuilder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent editIntent = new Intent(MoviesActivity.this, EditMovieActivity.class);
                     editIntent.putExtra("isNew",false);
                     editIntent.putExtra("title", movie.getTitle());
                     editIntent.putExtra("description", movie.getDescription());
                     editIntent.putExtra("year", movie.getYear());
                     editIntent.putExtra("rating", movie.getRating());
                     editIntent.putExtra("rottenId", movie.getRottenId());
                     editIntent.putExtra("smallImage", movie.getSmallImage());
                     editIntent.putExtra("largeImage", movie.getLargeImage());
                     startActivityForResult(editIntent,EDIT_MOVIE_REQUEST_CODE);
                }



            });

            editBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                return;
                }
            });




            Builder setNeutralButton = editBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear movie", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                   handler.deleteMovie(movie.getId());
                    moviesCursor = handler.getAllMoviesCursor();
                    adapter.swapCursor(moviesCursor);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Movie deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    

                }
            });         

            editBuilder.show();

            return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.rotten.tomatoes.MoviesActivity$MyCursorAdapter.bindView(MoviesActivity.java:209)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-16 03:41:28.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which line causes the error

Comment: I think it's these lines:

float numRate = 0;
        numRate = Float.parseFloat(movie.getRating().toString());
        rb.setRating(numRate);

Comment: it is indicated in your logcat just click it and it will redirect you to the line.

Comment: I know, I posted the lines around 209 which is the one indicated in the LogCat, thanks!

Comment: Specifically, what is line 209?

Comment: numRate = Float.parseFloat(movie.getRating().toString());

Comment: null would be the rating in your move class

Comment: I initialized it with 0 but it did not help